# Silverlight binding not working

Tags: silverlight, binding

In Silverlight 4, I have a content control to which i bind with

```
AddEditUser.DataContext=SomeUser;
```

The problem is when I enter data in the fields, I checked the object and it doesn't contain the data I enter in the fields.

```
<ContentControl Name="AddEditUser">
            <Grid Width="392" Height="183">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="77*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="168" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Add/Edit User"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Width="50" Content="New" Click="Button_Click" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  >
                    <Button Width="50" Content="Save" Click="Button_Click_1" />
                    <Button Width="50" Content="Delete" Click="Button_Click_2" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="User name:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Username}" Name="UserName" Width="168"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Password:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Password}" Width="168"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="First name:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="168"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Last name:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"   Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="168"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Admin:"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Name="AdminCheckbox"  Content="{Binding Path=Admin}" Width="168"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="Title:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="168"></TextBox>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="Email:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Email}" Width="168"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </ContentControl>
```

Comment: If i assign an object with data it shows the data.

Comment: It just doesn't get the modifications in the object

Comment: Instead of adding these comment please add to the question. That will improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TwoWay` binding in your text boxes to get the data entered in the fields to object. The default binding mode is one way.